# How to access to a WMS or WMTS from Qt QML Map

Tags: qt, qml, qtlocation

I would like to know if it is possible to access to a **Web Map Service** or **Web Map Tile Service** from a QML map. As far as I know, there isn't a **geoservice** plugin available to do it, so it needs to be developed I guess.

The WMTS might be something like: `http://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&hl=en&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}` or `https://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`.

The code of my QML map is very simple:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    width: 512
    height: 512
    title: qsTr("Title")
    visible: true

    Plugin {
        id: mapPlugin
        name: 'osm' // esri
    }

    Map {
        id: map
        plugin: mapPlugin
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(60.170448, 24.942046) // Helsinki
        zoomLevel: 14

        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

I didn't find any available solution that solve this. So, how can I write a geoservice plugin that performs WMTS requests based on (x,y,z) triplets?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to write your own plugin. I am about to do the same based upon this repo https://github.com/dirkvdb/qt-location-plugin-wmts/tree/develop/plugin